# Downloading Files from my server to jump server to my laptop

Tags: python

I have a complex environment. I need to run some script on a server which is accessible from only a jump server.

Web Server (need to run script /home/hno3.sh  which generates a file /tmp/hno3.txt)

Jump Server : Transfer file hno3.txt from Web server to here

Laptop : Transfer file hno3.txt from jump server to here

This is what I have written, which is obviously not sufficient:

```
import os
import paramiko
mycommand = raw_input("Enter your command ")
excel = []
with open('server.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        server = line.rstrip()
        username, password = ('ibmadmin', 'password')
        ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()

        ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())

        ssh.load_host_keys(os.path.expanduser(os.path.join("~", ".ssh", "known_hosts")))

        ssh.connect(server, username=username, timeout=60)
        ssh_stdin, ssh_stdout, ssh_stderr = ssh.exec_command(mycommand)
        print "For Server " + server
        output1 = ssh_stdout.read()
        print ">", output1.rstrip()
        excel.append(output1.rstrip())

        ssh.close()
```

When executing, I am giving scp command, to download files from webserver to jump server.

I am unable to figure out how to execute script on webserver. Is there a way to login from laptop to jump server, then to webserver to run a script? My script will be running on laptop.